# Gmail for outgoing emails?

Tags: 10.04, server, gmail

How to setup GMail on Ubuntu 10.04 **server** for sending emails using only console?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command-line email client called Mutt: http://www.mutt.org/

It supports POP3 and IMAP, and can be used with Gmail. The steps to configure Mutt for use with Gmail is given here: http://www.andrews-corner.org/mutt.html